# Automated way of starting an instance run file and than terminating

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-emr

I would like to have a python script that helps me to start an ec2-instance load a python script from the s3-bucket and get it run once the script is completed I would like to get it terminated ,all I want this is to get done in an automated I am new to AWS and have a lot of confusion, any help appreciated.

Comment: aws lambda seems to be much more suitable for this task. I'd suggest considering it

Comment: But how can I go with just a python file doing all this without the use of lambda.?

Comment: have you looked into boto3 documentation? what exactly confuses you?

Comment: Nope I haven't looked totally will have look at the documentation properly once again

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS SSM for this with [Automation Documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-documents.html)

Create a document with the following actions (follow the documentation):

- [aws:runInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html#automation-action-runinstance) to start the instance.
- [aws:runCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html#automation-action-runcommand) to download your script from s3 and run it.
- [aws:changeInstanceState](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-actions.html#automation-action-changestate) to terminate the instance.

Answer (score 0):

To work with AWS services using python, you should use boto3.

For creating and terminating an EC2 instance through python code refer the following boto3/EC2 documentation:

[Create EC2 instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Subnet.create_instances)

[Terminate EC2 instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.terminate_instances)

For creating and terminating an EMR cluster through python code refer the following boto3/EMR documentations :

[Create EMR cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow)

[Terminate EMR cluster](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.terminate_job_flows)

To execute your script lying on S3, you can use remote ssh to the EC2/EMR master node. For EMR you can also execute the script as a step using add_job_flow_steps of boto3/emr as described [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.add_job_flow_steps).